# SmartGWT not able to parse data in the DataSource.transformResponse() method

Tags: gwt, javascript-objects, smartgwt

I need some help please...

I am working with a GWT enabled web application.  I am using the gwt-2.3.0 SDK.

I have a method that extends the DataSource class and uses the transformResponse method:

```
public class DeathRecordXmlDS extends DataSource { 

 protected void transformResponse(DSResponse response, DSRequest request, Object data){
     super.transformResponse(response, request, data);
 } 

}
```

As I understand, the transformResponse() method should get control and at this point, I will have access to the data that is being provided to the Client side of my application.  I am trying to work with the Object data parameter (the third parameter) that is passed in.

I am expecting an XML formatted string to be passed in.  The XML will contain data (a count field) that I need to access and use.

I don't seem to be getting an XML string.  Here's what I know...

I do see the XML data being passed to my webapp (the client).  I can see this because I inspect the webpage that I am working with and I see the Response data.  Here's an example of something that I expect to receive:

```
XML data from Query:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Collection numRecords="0">
    <DeathRecords/>
</Collection>
```

The above XML is valid (I checked it in a Validator).  This is a case where there was no data (No Death Records) being returned to my application.  The numRecords XML attribute is set to "0".  Of course, If I do have records returned the numRecords will contain the number of records and I'll get that same number of DeathRecord nodes.

I am not getting the above data (or, I don't know how to work with it) in the transformResponse() method.

Here's what I've done to try to figure this out...

The Object data parameter... it is a JavaScriptObject.  I know this because I did a .getClass().getName() on it:

```
DeathRecordXmlDS::transformResponse()      data.getClass().getName(): com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$
```

Then, to try to work with it, I converted it to a String:

```
        com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject dataJS = (com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject)data;
    System.out.println("DeathRecordXmlDS::transformResponse()     data as a JavaScriptObject: "+dataJS.toString());
```

The contents of 'data' formatted as a String look like:

```
DeathRecordXmlDS::transformResponse()     data as a JavaScriptObject: [XMLDoc <Collection>]
```

So, it looks like I have something that has to do with my 'Collection' node, but not a String of XML data that I can parse and get to my numRecords attribute.

What do I need to do to gain access to the XML in the transformResponse() method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for an additional period of time I was able to read the XML data that I am working with.  I used the following piece of code:

```
    try{
        JsArray<JavaScriptObject> nodes = ((JavaScriptObject) XMLTools.selectNodes(data, "/Collection/@numRecords")).cast();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
          com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element element = (com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element) nodes.get(i);

          numRecords = element.getNodeValue();
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        //  If Parsing fails, capture the exception 
        System.out.println("DeathRecordXmlDS::transformResponse()     Not able to parse the XML");  
    }
```

I think the first step to solving this was understanding that the parameter 'data' of type Object was really a JavaScriptObject.  I learned this after looking at the .getClass() and .getName().  This helped me understand what I was working with:

```
System.out.println("DeathRecordXmlDS::transformResponse()     data.getClass().getName(): "+data.getClass().getName());
```

Once I knew it was a JavaScriptObject, I was able to do a little more focused of a Google search for what I was trying to accomplish. I was a little surprised that the XMLTools.selectNodes() function worked the way it did, but the end result is that I was able to read the numRecords attribute.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think your data object is already translated to a javascript collection.

Maybe you could use the utility class [XMLTools](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/XMLTools.html) to retrieve your numRecords information:

```
Integer numRecords = Integer.parseInt(XMLTools.selectString(data, "Collection/@numRecords"));
```

Comment: I failed to mention that the code I am working with did use the very XMLTools function that you mention.  I believe it used to work (I assume), but now, the selectString function returns an empty string.  I just doesn't work.  I was looking for a new way to solve the problem (reading the numRecords value).  Possibly iterating over the XML structure.

Comment: I have run into the same problem.  Existing code in my project implies that using XMLTools to select a string directly from the rawData parameter used to work, but in my usage this only returns null even though my XML is formatted correctly.  I am interested to know if something else needs to be specified to preserve the raw XML data rather than having it converted to JSOs.